# Rotate canvas should not rotate it's children

Tags: wpf

Is there any way to rotate only the canvas without rotating it's children like image, geometry etc in it? Any help anyone could produce would highly be appreciated.

Many thanks
Ratheesh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kent Boogarts suggestion is what i thought of initially too, it's not even that hard to implement since one can directly bind to the `Inverse` transform of the Canvas:

```
<ItemsControl>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Canvas>
                <Canvas.RenderTransform>
                    <RotateTransform />
                </Canvas.RenderTransform>
            </Canvas>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ContentControl Content="{Binding}"
                            RenderTransform="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Canvas},
                                                      Path=RenderTransform.Inverse}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: Thanks dude, this(RenderTransform.Inverse) was sort of anwer I desired. It worked well when the canvas was rotated. But anyway to not to apply the inverse when given translate transform to canvas? When rotate+translate is applied(rotated and then moved) to the canvas, it should only inverse the rotation?

Comment: Then you have to use a TransformGroup, just change the binding path to `RenderTransform.Children[1].Inverse` where of course the index needs to point to the right transform.

Comment: Yeah.. dear friend, you are absolutely right.. I have used RenderTransform.Children[1].Inverse and it worked.. thanks once again dude.

Answer (score 2):

I think only way is to rotate `Canvas` and rotate it's children in another direction.

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no way of doing this unless you apply the opposite transformation to each child. Perhaps if you explain what you're trying to achieve, there is likely an easier way to do so.