# Binding zoom value to control's size

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, binding, datatemplate

I have a `Canvas` with some images (24x24 in size) on it and I also have a scrollbar that zooms in and out the canvas.

I would like to make the images stay the same size when resizing the canvas so I thought of binding the width / height of the images to the zoom value so that their width / height will be dependant of the zoom value (So, for example, they'll be `Width = Width / ZoomValue` or something similar)

How can I obtain this behavior using WPF and binding?

Thanks!

Comment: I was also thinking of maybe applying a `ScaleTransform` on my images that will bind to the zoom value and be `1 / ZoomValue`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the images all have a width of 24, bind to ZoomValue and use an IValueConverter:
(ZoomValue has to be on your ViewModel)

```
<Image Source="..." Width="{Binding ZoomValue, Converter={StaticResource ZoomToWidthConverter}" />
```

And the IValueConverter:

```
public class ZoomToWidthConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            Double imgOriginalWidth = 24;
            return imgOriginalWidth / System.Convert.ToDouble(value);
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            Double imgOriginalWidth = 24;
            return System.Convert.ToDouble(value) * imgOriginalWidth;
        }
}
```

The Resources of the Canvas must hold a key for ZoomToWidthConverter:

```
<Canvas>
<Canvas.Resources>
<local:ZoomToWidthConverter x:Key="ZoomToWidthConverter " />
</Canvas.Resources>
</Canvas>
```

If the images can have different original width, use a MultiBinding along with an IMultiValueConverter.

Comment: Merry Christmas to you sir =)

Answer (score 1):

Starting point is to define a converter that you'll use in binding, here are some links that can be useful:

1. http://www.wpftutorial.net/ValueConverters.html
2. http://blogs.imeta.co.uk/FMoreno/archive/2008/11/07/498.aspx

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! Will try these! Do you have a more specific code example for my problem? That's the way I learn best

Comment: I haven't done it myself (means i haven't create a converter myself, i have used the built in one (boolToVisConverter) so i don't have any. Look at Baboon's answer below, he has posted the code of creating a converter!

Answer (score 1):

Not very sure if there is somethign built-in done on this subject already in `WPF 4.0`, also cause this feature was requested long years ago by users. The only valuable solution, imo, that you can apply is to assign your `childcontrol.RenderTransform` to *inverse* of the `transformation matrix` of its parent, so `canvas`.

**Let a databinding to assign correct value**

By doing so, hope it's clear, you reset transformation applied to the canvas and get the "old" matrix. Considering that you're talking about a **single** transformation (there is no `Translation`, `Scale` and `Rotation` made insequence) you have to get mathematically predictable (so correct) "original" matrix (they call it `Identity`).

Look on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5855008/rotate-canvas-should-not-rotate-its-children) answer, which refers to another one again.

Hope this helps.